# Different versions, unable to resume activity when onActivityResult called

Tags: android, exception

I have made an android app with a button(for scan) and a webview component.
If the button_scan being pressed, it will execute startActivityForResult to call activity zxing to scan barcode and QR code.
After zxing finished, I write onActivityResult to handle the data.

This app works fine on the Android V2.2.2 until now, and no exception occurs.

However, if this app ran on the Android V2.3 or V4.0.4, it will bump out an exception(java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity).
This exception will occur when onActivityResult being called.

I have printed the global variable(CURRENTWEBPAGE) for test and discovered that, before calling startActivityForResult, CURRENTWEBPAGE has value, but 
CURRENTWEBPAGE was null after onActivityResult being called.

I am curious about whether the versions of android matters in the case. 
Will all the global members be cleared?

Can anyone who had bumped into this situation giving me an solution to solve this problem?

If there is any further information you need, please feel free to tell me.

Your reply will be appreciated.

The following is my app code.

```
public class MyApp extends Activity
{
    private String CURRENTWEBPAGE;//which will be set value whenvever webview changed.
    private WebView webView_main;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initActivity_web();
        ...
            ...
    }

    public void initActivity_web()
    {

        // add Listener to button_SCAN
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_SCAN)).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),CURRENTWEBPAGE);
                    // CURRENTWEBPAGE has value here.

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Toast popup = Toast.makeText(NEOMove.this, "Please install Zxing Barcode Scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    popup.show();

                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String QRCodeContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                String newURL =  convertToLCMOBILESUPPORTActionUrl(CURRENTWEBPAGE);//exception occur
                //because CURRENTWEBPAGE = null;
                //java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

                webView_main.loadUrl(newURL  + QRCodeContent);
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // TODO Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Add -- 2012/09/20

Hi,
I discover that the onCreate of parent app(My App) will be called before onActivityResult.
Despite keeping these variables in the SharedPreferences, the webview of MyApp is recreated with the new session id.
This will not work for me, because, after scanning the barcode, I need to send a request with a permission which logged in the cache of destroyed webview.
Is there any way to make the parent app not to be destroyed?

The following is my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you app is the android garbage collector that has removed the calling activity from memory. Try making CURRENTWEBPAGE static.

```
static private String CURRENTWEBPAGE;
```